# convert a flat list into a tree with limited number of nodes per depth

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

i'm search a solution for the following task:

i have a flat list with a lot of data.

Now i want to transfrom this list into an tree with the following rules:

- all of my listitems  should be leafs
- the number of nodes per tree depth should be limit the a certain limit
- nodes can be nested with unlimited depth

i think it's like an k-ary (with k is the node limit per level) tree, but maybe this thing has annother name.

The background for this task is a visualisation problem of my list in a radial tree. Displaying all leafs on the first level in the radial tree doesn't look good when there are too much. So i think it's better to insert some nodes to group my data when the level limit is reached. The resulting tree should be able to display the leafs in a better visually way.

is there an algorithm or even better an implementation for this task?

Thanks for any pointer or infos.

Comment: Should the tree keep the elements in some special order (e.g. sorted), or simply in the order from the list?

Comment: special ordering is not so important. the list entries has some sort of order.

Comment: Does the `k` limit the total number of nodes at a level? K-ary means k child nodes per internal node (no per-level limit) which is a different thing.

Comment: k should limit the number of siblings per level

Answer (score 4):

Let's say `N`, the number of items in your list is 4 and `K=2`. So this will be a binary tree.

Step 1: Create 2 nodes

```
  P1        P2

1    2    3    4
```

Step 2: Create links between the 2 nodes and `K` of the leaf nodes

```
  P1        P2
 /  \      /  \
1    2    3    4
```

Step 3: Create another node

```
       P5

  P1        P2
 /  \      /  \
1    2    3    4
```

Step 4: Create the links between that node and the 2 previous nodes you created

```
       P5
    /      \
  P1        P2
 /  \      /  \
1    2    3    4
```

See the pattern? You can do this iteratively pretty easily for any such `N` and `K`. You have to worry a little about cases where `N` is not a perfect power of `K`. Basically the number of children of every node is at most ceil(N/K).

Comment: Isn't the constraint K nodes *per level*? If this is the case, then the leaf level breaks the constraint. If the constraint is K children per node, then of course it's OK.